# cannot open files on Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I use a Note 8, and when I try to upload documents from Dropbox with the browser, it tells me "file cannot be opened".

Comment: Are you trying to _upload_ files _from_ your tablet _to_ Dropbox, or _download_ files _from_ Dropbox _to_ your tablet?

Comment: I may not be getting the terms right . Am trying to send my resume which is on Dropbox to a job site,  but it keeps telling me file cannot be opened. Kindly assist. Also I will like the option of choosing a document from either my device or Dropbox,  right now I can only choose from Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've selected Dropbox as the default for uploading files. You can test this by going to `Settings -> Apps -> Dropbox` and tapping `Clear defaults`. Now, when you open your browser and try to upload files, it should ask what program you want to use to select the file.

In my personal opinion, you should only upload files from your device, since not all apps support uploading via the browser. If the file you need to upload is only on Dropbox, you can download it from the app by long-pressing the file and selecting `Export -> Save to SD Card`.

Comment: I may have chosen Dropbox as my default, but I don't know how I did that nor how to reverse it. I checked settings but the clear defaults button is not active - it says "no defaults set". I tried removing my Dropbox account from settings and unlinking my device from Dropbox. I cannot delete Dropbox cause it came with the device. My last option would be to factory reset, but that is extreme. When I try to upload a document my options are: camera, camcorder, sound recorder, music track, Dropbox, gallery, music player, Samsung link. I used to be able to upload from files, but the option is gone.

Comment: Try installing a file explorer, such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). This should install itself into the upload method selection screen and you should be able to upload all file types.